# Calling a function with varying arguments isn't working

Tags: javascript

I can't see why I'm not getting "name2" printed. It's my first Scopes exercise.  Any tips to get better at finding these mistakes or it's just practice? I've been looking at this for half an hour and it seems perfect to me.

```
// The scope of `random` is too loose 
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

const getRandEvent = () => {
  if (random === 0) {
    return 'Marathon';
  } else if (random === 1) {
    return 'Triathlon';
  } else if (random === 2) {
    return 'Pentathlon';
  }
};

// The scope of `days` is too tight 
const getTrainingDays = event => {
  let days;
  if (event === 'Marathon') {
    days = 50;
  } else if (event === 'Triathlon') {
    days = 100;
  } else if (event === 'Pentathlon') {
    days = 200;
  }

  return days;
};
const name = 'Nala';
const name2 = 'Warren'
// The scope of `name` is too tight 
const logEvent = event => {
  console.log(`${name}'s event is: ${event}`);
};

const logTime = days => {
  console.log(`${name}'s time to train is: ${days} days`);
};

const event = getRandEvent();
const days = getTrainingDays(event);
// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(name, event);
logTime(name, days);

const event2 = getRandEvent();
const days2 = getTrainingDays(event2);

// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(event2, name2);
logTime(days2, name2);
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
Nala's event is: Marathon
Nala's time to train is: 200 days
Nala's event is: Triathlon
Nala's time to train is: 100 days
```

This is what I should get

```
Nala's event is: Marathon
Nala's time to train is: 200 days
Warren's event is: Triathlon
Warren's time to train is: 100 days
```

Comment: Your `logEvent` and `logTime` functions are written to take only one parameter.

Comment: Like Pointy said, simply change the code to `const logEvent = (event, name) => {
  console.log(`${name}'s event is: ${event}`);
};`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made the changes and now I'm getting

"Nala's event is: Marathon
Nala's time to train is: 50 days
Marathon's event is: Warren
50's time to train is: Warren days"

```
    // The scope of `random` is too loose 
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

const getRandEvent = () => {
  if (random === 0) {
    return 'Marathon';
  } else if (random === 1) {
    return 'Triathlon';
  } else if (random === 2) {
    return 'Pentathlon';
  }
};

// The scope of `days` is too tight 
const getTrainingDays = event => {
  let days;
  if (event === 'Marathon') {
    days = 50;
  } else if (event === 'Triathlon') {
    days = 100;
  } else if (event === 'Pentathlon') {
    days = 200;
  }

  return days;
};
const name = 'Nala';
const name2 = 'Warren';
// The scope of `name` is too tight 
const logEvent = (name,event) => {
  console.log(`${name}'s event is: ${event}`);
};

const logTime = (name,days) => {
  console.log(`${name}'s time to train is: ${days} days`);
};

const event = getRandEvent();
const days = getTrainingDays(event);
// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(name, event);
logTime(name, days);

const event2 = getRandEvent();
const days2 = getTrainingDays(event2);

// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(event2, name2);
logTime(days2, name2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with changing the parameter list of the functions, you reversed the arguments when calling the functions the second time. See below.

```js
// The scope of `random` is too loose 
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

const getRandEvent = () => {
  if (random === 0) {
    return 'Marathon';
  } else if (random === 1) {
    return 'Triathlon';
  } else if (random === 2) {
    return 'Pentathlon';
  }
};

// The scope of `days` is too tight 
const getTrainingDays = event => {
  let days;
  if (event === 'Marathon') {
    days = 50;
  } else if (event === 'Triathlon') {
    days = 100;
  } else if (event === 'Pentathlon') {
    days = 200;
  }

  return days;
};
const name = 'Nala';
const name2 = 'Warren'
// The scope of `name` is too tight 
const logEvent = (name, event) => {
  console.log(`${name}'s event is: ${event}`);
};

const logTime = (name, days) => {
  console.log(`${name}'s time to train is: ${days} days`);
};

const event = getRandEvent();
const days = getTrainingDays(event);
// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(name, event);
logTime(name, days);

const event2 = getRandEvent();
const days2 = getTrainingDays(event2);

// Define a `name` variable. Use it as an argument after updating logEvent and logTime 


logEvent(name2, event2);
logTime(name2, days2);
```

Comment: If want the two calls to output different results, you must define `random` inside `getRandEvent`